# How to use PrinttoPrinter in crystal report viewer and print on multiple printers?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to print direct to the printer in c# windows application ,

I am using the following code to show the report on the screen :

```
                int order_id = Convert.ToInt32(textorder.Text);
                RPT.OrdersReport report = new RPT.OrdersReport();
                RPT.RPT_TESTS frm = new RPT.RPT_TESTS();
                report.SetDataSource(order.GetOrderDetailsForPrint(order_id));
                frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
                frm.ShowDialog();
```

How to update my code to use Print to printer and how to print on multiple printers also I have A4 printer report and Label Printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print to the printer use the following code to print to the default printer :

```
int order_id = Convert.ToInt32(textOrder.Text);
RPT.OrdersReport report = new RPT.OrdersReport();
RPT.RPT_TESTS frm = new RPT.RPT_TESTS();
report.SetDataSource(order.GetOrderDetailsForPrint(order_id));
report.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

To print to the second printer use the following code :

```
RPT.barcode myreport = new RPT.barcode();
myreport.SetDatabaseLogon("User_Name", "Password");
RPT.RPT_TESTS myform = new RPT.RPT_TESTS();
myreport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Second Printer Name ";
myreport.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```